# GridView RowUpdating returns old values after PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got a problem with my GridView. When I try to edit my GridView, I only get the old values in return.

Here's the RowUpdating event:

```
protected void grid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    TextBox nVorname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("newVorname");
    TextBox nNachname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("newNachname");
    TextBox nTelnr = (TextBox)row.FindControl("newTelnr");
    TextBox nEmail = (TextBox)row.FindControl("newEmail");
    HiddenField tid = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("id");

    grid.EditIndex = -1;

    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;Integrated Security=true;database=Telefonbuch;");
    sqlConn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update dasOertliche set vorname= @vorname, nachname=@nachname, telefonnr =@telnr, email =@email where id = @id", sqlConn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@vorname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@vorname"].Value = nVorname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@nachname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@nachname"].Value = nNachname.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@email"].Value = nEmail.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@telnr", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@telnr"].Value = nTelnr.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = tid.Value;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConn.Close();
    bind();
}
```

The TemplateField from the .aspx:

```
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Vorname">
    <ItemTemplate>    <%#Eval ("vorname") %></ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="newVorname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("vorname") %>'>
    </asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
   </columns>
```

And my GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grid" BorderWidth="0px" CellPadding="10" 
CellSpacing="10" HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
AutoGenerateEditButton="True" onrowcancelingedit="grid_RowCancelingEdit" 
onrowediting="grid_RowEditing" onrowupdating="grid_RowUpdating" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Like I said, it always returns the old values. Any suggestions?

My Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bind();
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        bind();
    }
}
```

My bind():

```
 public void bind()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;Integrated Security=true;database=Telefonbuch;");
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlComm = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, vorname AS 'Vorname', nachname AS 'Nachname', telefonnr, email AS 'E-Mail' FROM dasOertliche ORDER BY nachname ASC", sqlConn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sqlComm.Fill(ds, "dasOertliche");
        grid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        grid.DataBind();
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bind();
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        bind();
    }
}
```

is wrong.

It should be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        bind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `GridView1.DataBind()` in the end.

Comment: Where in the end? I do it on the very last part of the RowUpdating.

Answer (score 1):

On Pageload put your bind grid code in following condition

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if (!Page.IsPostBack)
               {
                  bind();
               }
        }
```

Comment: i have update the answer please try like this remove the bind(); which is above the if (!Page.IsPostBack) line.and keep only the bind(); which is in if condition.